# Сколько грамматических основ?

Tags: синтаксис, сказуемые, однородные-члены

В варианте ОГЭ (Статград) вопрос: сколько грамматических основ в предложении:

> В другое время я мог бы обидеться, уехать, а тут почему-то остался – ну вот не хотелось.

При проверке возникли разногласия: 2 или 3?

Comment: а в связи с чем был удален ответ и комментарий к нему?

Comment: В ответе, данном Людмилой, написано то, что я и хотел сказать, поэтому восстанавливать свой не буду. В школе, чтобы не ругаться с учителем, проще согласиться с тремя грамматическими основами.

Comment: но средний ученик (на которого рассчитан экзамен) не подозревает о спорах ученых и видит 2 основы, первая: я мог бы обидеться, уехать, а остался, вторая: не хотелось(((

Comment: Увы, так устроено современное обучение русскому языку в школе. От этого можно было бы уйти, потому что бесполезно знать, сколько в «В другое время я мог бы обидеться, уехать, а тут почему-то остался» грамматических основ — две или три, но нет, нам до этого далеко )) Еще долго, наверно, буду давить типами придаточных и т. п. В общем, вам наверняка рассказывали, что одн. чл. должны быть в одной грам. форме. Если не говорили, косяк учителей. В любом случае доказать убежденной в чем-то русичке, что могут быть варианты, невозможно )

Comment: @Aer, Я не "русичка", а "любитель", но убежден вот в чем. Иногда однородные члены могут быть в разной грамматической форме, но тогда между ними должно быть нечто общее, пересиливающее различия между ними. Так сказать, сила притяжения сильнее силы отталкивания. А у нас "остался" не соединяется с явно однородными "обидеться" и "уехать" ни по грамматической форме, ни по зависимым словам, "мог бы" входит в сказуемое вместе с "обидеться и уехать", а "остался" стоит одиноко в стороне.

Comment: @М_Г ну грамматически они связаны: и синтаксически (субъект один и тот же), и морфологически (формы глаголов *мог бы, остался* согласуются с 1 л. ед. ч.) — более того, семантически: деятель один и тот же.

Comment: И, если что, русичек я никак не хотел обидеть, но факт в том, что большинство из них неотступно следуют тому, чему учили их в пединституте. А программу хорошо бы переделать, что на данный момент без бунта на корабле невозможно.

Comment: М_Г, получается, что в предложении "я мог бы купить подарок и подарить его, но воздержался" тоже 2 основы?

Comment: Я не такой уж большой теоретик (совсем не теоретик), и в этом случае не уверен. Скорее всего, тут как раз та ситуация, о которой написала Людмила ("в науке есть разные подходы"). В отличие от предыдущего предложения в пользу одной основы можно отметить, что "воздержался" не имеет зависимых слов, а наличие союза И позволяет увидеть как бы две группы однородных сказуемых.

Comment: @М_Г конечно здесь та ситуация, в науке вообще часто такое бывает. С синтаксическими теориями особенно...

Comment: Все-таки восстановил ответ, посмотрите )

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 6):

В другое время **я мог бы обидеться**, **уехать**, а тут почему- то **остался** – ну вот **не хотелось**. - 3 грамматические основы.

В другое время **я мог бы обидеться**, **уехать**,- полное двусоставное

а тут почему- то **остался** – неполное двусоставное с пропуском подлежащего

ну вот **не хотелось**.- односоставное безличное.

Для ОГЭ некорректное задание, потому что в науке есть разные подходы к таким предложениям. Одни учёные считают предложение типа *"В другое время я мог бы обидеться, уехать, а тут почему- то остался"*  простым с однородными сказуемыми, другие - сложносочинённым, объясняя это тем, что описаны две разные ситуации: в одно время мог уехать, а в это время остался - составы сказуемых разные, значит, это уже другая основа другого предложения.

Comment: По-моему, можно спорить об однородности сказуемых, если их два:  я мог бы обидеться, а тут остался. Но у нас три сказуемых, и то, что объединяет первое сказуемое со вторым, "отталкивает" третье.

Comment: так, по-вашему, 2 или 3 основы?

Comment: 3 грамматические основы.

Answer (score 2):

Постараюсь дать ответ с опорой на учебники.

1. Если сказуемые соединены друг с другом сочинительными союзами или перечислительной интонацией (на письме в этом случае ставится запятая) и согласованы с одним и тем же подлежащим, то они однородные, а предложение простое. («Русский язык: учебное пособие для старших классов школ гуманитарного профиля» В. А. Багрянцева, Издательство Московского университета, Москва, 2017. Грифа Минобра нет.)
2. Однородными называются члены предложения, которые относятся к одному и тому же члену предложения, отвечают на один и тот же вопрос и выполняют одинаковую синтаксическую функцию. (Русский язык. 8 класс.  Тростенцова Л.А., Ладыженская Т.А. и др. Москва, 2014. Гриф Минобра есть, распространенный учебник.)

Проанализируем предложение по каждому (1–2) из определений и сделаем обоснованный вывод, с которым можно подойти к учителю и потребовать апелляции.

Итак, приступим.

### Определение № 1

Нужно, чтобы: ***(А)*** сказуемые соединялись сочинительным союзом **или** перечислительной интонацией (при которой ставится запятая); ***(Б)*** сказуемые были согласованы с одним и тем же подлежащим.

Критерий ***(А)*** выполнен: «Я мог бы обидеться, уехать, **а** *(сочинительный противительный союз)* <...> остался».

Критерий ***(Б)*** выполнен: «Я (1 л. ед. ч.) мог (1 л. ед. ч. + м. р. пр. вр.) бы обидеться, уехать, а <...> остался (1 л. ед. ч. + м. р. пр. вр.).

Таким образом, по опеределению № 1 **сказуемые однородны**.

### Определение № 2

Нужно, чтобы: ***(В)*** сказуемые относились к одному и тому же подлежащему; ***(Г)*** отвечали на один и тот же вопрос; ***(Д)*** выполняли одну и ту же синтаксическую функцию, т. е. были, собственно, сказуемыми (в учебнике понятие, кажется, не толкуется, поэтому мы вольны определять его по-своему).

Критерий ***(В)*** выполнен: «Я мог бы обидеться, уехать, **а** <...> остался» — и мог бы обидеться, уехать, и остался один и тот же деятель — *я*.

Критерий ***(Г)*** не выполнен: «Я *(что **делал**?)* мог бы обидеться, уехать, а <...> *(что **сделал**?)* остался» — вопросы разные.

Критерий ***(Д)*** выполнен. Думаю, и так очевидно, что мы говорим о сказуемых.

Таким образом, по опеределению № 2 **сказуемые *не* однородны**.

### Вывод

Как видно, по разным определениям из разных учебников выходят различные итоги. Таким образом, в предложении может быть и две, и три грамматические основы — всё зависит от того, какому определению однородных сказуемых следовать.

Если ваш учитель согласится пойти вам навстречу и засчитает ваш вариант ответа, то хорошо. Однако скорее всего он скажет, что по учебнику, который соответствует программе, критерии схожи с ***(В–Д)***, поэтому основы три — и точка.

Буду ждать развития событий :)

Comment: тоже считаю, что 2 основы, но учитель поставил ошибку и доказывал, что 3 основы(

Comment: Учитель поставил ошибку, потому что у него были ключи к проверке, это же Статград, он приходит с ключами, так что спорить нужно не с ним, а с разработчиками тестов Статграда.

Comment: @Людмила если выбирать с кем спорить, то уж точно с учителем, а не с эфемерными разработчиками. В конце концов, именно учитель ставит отметку.

Comment: Спасибо за такой подробный разбор!!!

Comment: @ Aer  Не очень понятно про вопросы. Разный вид, кажется, не мешает сказуемым быть однородными, например: Обошёл Лис вокруг Ежа, вздохнул и говорит... Ну чем не однородные сказуемые, а вопросы разные. В нашем же случае даже наклонение у глаголов разное, как к ним вопросы задавать?

Comment: @Jasmin если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам стоит искать на него ответ в редакции, где выпускали учебник для учеников 8 класса. Вид и вопрос неразрывно связаны, и при изменении одного неизбежно меняется другое. Мне ближе взгляд, описанный в учебнике филфака МГУ.

Comment: Я просто хотела узнать Ваше мнение: могут ли глаголы разного вида быть однородными сказуемыми?(А на вопрос я уже ответила).

Comment: @Jasmin могут, например: Я выпью вина и грущу.

Answer (score 2):

**Для школы (ОГЭ) здесь  две основы.**

Школьникам достаточно понимать следующее: хотя субъект действия один и тот же, но в первой части однородные сказуемые относятся к подлежащему "я", а в во второй части подлежащего нет, предложение безличное. Это школьный уровень 9 класса.

**Для вузов скорее 3 основы:**

Первая часть предложения (**В другое время** я мог бы обидеться, уехать, а **тут** почему- то остался)  расчлененная, дифференцированная  разными наречиями, она сходна с СПП: Хотя в другое время я мог бы обидеться, уехать, а (но) тут почему-то остался.

Союз А для однородных сказуемых вообще не подходит: я мог бы обидеться, уехать, а  остался.